# Traceroute - Sometimes the sockets fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, traceroute

I'm writing traceroute in Python3 as an exercise. It's working quite well, but every now and then, the trace will be unable to receive an answer from a certain hop and keep incrementing the TTL without ever getting a response. The regular linux traceroute program does not suffer from this problem so it has to be something in my code.

I've tried different variations, but they all suffer from the same problem. I'll run the trace on 8.8.8.8 and 4 out of 5 times, it works perfectly.

I've tried creating sockets using the context manager (with socket as ...) and also manually.

```
import os
import random
import socket
import sys
import time

class Traceroute:
def __init__(self, dest, maxhops=30, port=random.randrange(33434,33534), host=''):
    self.dest = dest
    self.maxhops = maxhops
    self.port = port
    self.host = host
    self.hops = []

# Function for creating new sockets
def get_socket(self,type,proto=0):
    s = socket.socket(
        family=socket.AF_INET,
        type=type,
        proto=proto
    )
    s.bind((self.host,self.port))
    return s

# Do the trace and store hop information for later use
def get_path(self):
    try:
        self.dest_ip = socket.gethostbyname(self.dest)
        self.dest_name = socket.gethostbyaddr(self.dest)[0]
    except socket.gaierror as e:
        print(f'Error: {self.dest} - {e}')

    address = ['']
    ttl = 1
    while ttl < self.maxhops +1 and address[0] != self.dest_ip:
            receiver_socket = self.get_socket(socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.getprotobyname('icmp'))
            receiver_socket.settimeout(2)
            sender_socket = self.get_socket(socket.SOCK_DGRAM,socket.getprotobyname('udp'))
            sender_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP,socket.IP_TTL,ttl)
            sender_socket.sendto(b'',(self.dest_ip,self.port))
            tries = 3
            while tries > 0:
                starttime = time.time()
                try:
                    data, address = receiver_socket.recvfrom(1024)
                    latency = [round((time.time()-starttime)*1000,2)]
                    try:
                        hostname = socket.gethostbyaddr(address[0])[0]
                    except socket.herror as e:
                        hostname = address[0]
                    self.hops.append({
                        'address':address[0],
                        'hostname':hostname,
                        'latency': latency
                    })
                    tries = 0
                except socket.error:
                    tries -= 1
                    if tries == 0:
                        self.hops.append({
                            'address':None,
                            'hostname':ttl,
                            'latency':None
                            })
                finally:
                    receiver_socket.close()
                    sender_socket.close()
            ttl += 1
            os.system('clear')
            self.draw()

def draw(self):
    name = f'{self.dest_ip} - {self.dest_name}' if self.dest_name != self.dest_ip else self.dest_ip
    print(f'Traceroute to {name}')
    # Print the full hop list, for debugging
    for hop in self.hops:
        print(hop)
    # Print the hops in a readable fashion
    for hop in self.hops:
        if hop['address'] is None:
            print(f"{self.hops.index(hop)+1} - {'*':<50} - {'*':<50} - {'*':<50}")
        else:
            latencylen = len(hop['latency'])
            latencyavg = str(round(sum(hop['latency'])/latencylen,2)) + 'ms'
            name = f'{hop["address"]} - {hop["hostname"]}' if hop['address'] != hop['hostname'] else hop['address']
            print(f'{self.hops.index(hop)+1} - {name:<50} - {latencyavg:<50} - LEN:{latencylen:<50}')

def main():
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Please enter a destination')
else:
    trace = Traceroute(sys.argv[1])
    trace.get_path()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Here is the output when it completely bugs out:

self.hops is a list of dictionaries.

The stuff in {brackets} is the hop dictionary itself. I added it for debugging.
Note that hops 2 and 3 are identical. So the trace somehow ran against this hop twice. The number at the beginning of the line is the list index, which also represents the TTL. I usually reach 8.8.8.8 by the 9th hop, but in this case it just keeps going, incrementing the TTL until it reaches the maximum.

```
Traceroute to 8.8.8.8 - google-public-dns-a.google.com
{'address': '192.168.1.1', 'hostname': '_gateway', 'latency': [8.21]}
{'address': '104.195.128.122', 'hostname': '104-195-128-122.cpe.teksavvy.com', 'latency': [1572.38]}
{'address': '104.195.128.122', 'hostname': '104-195-128-122.cpe.teksavvy.com', 'latency': [15.97]}
{'address': '104.195.129.9', 'hostname': '104-195-129-9.cpe.teksavvy.com', 'latency': [27.22]}
{'address': '206.248.155.92', 'hostname': 'ae10-0-bdr01-tor2.teksavvy.com', 'latency': [20.05]}
{'address': '206.248.155.10', 'hostname': 'ae12-0-bdr01-tor.teksavvy.com', 'latency': [27.2]}
{'address': None, 'hostname': 7, 'latency': None}
{'address': None, 'hostname': 8, 'latency': None}
{'address': None, 'hostname': 9, 'latency': None}
{'address': None, 'hostname': 10, 'latency': None}
{'address': None, 'hostname': 11, 'latency': None}
{'address': None, 'hostname': 12, 'latency': None}
{'address': None, 'hostname': 13, 'latency': None}
{'address': None, 'hostname': 14, 'latency': None}
{'address': None, 'hostname': 15, 'latency': None}
1 - 192.168.1.1 - _gateway                             - 8.21ms                                             - LEN:1                                                 
2 - 104.195.128.122 - 104-195-128-122.cpe.teksavvy.com - 1572.38ms                                          - LEN:1                                                 
3 - 104.195.128.122 - 104-195-128-122.cpe.teksavvy.com - 15.97ms                                            - LEN:1                                                 
4 - 104.195.129.9 - 104-195-129-9.cpe.teksavvy.com     - 27.22ms                                            - LEN:1                                                 
5 - 206.248.155.92 - ae10-0-bdr01-tor2.teksavvy.com    - 20.05ms                                            - LEN:1                                                 
6 - 206.248.155.10 - ae12-0-bdr01-tor.teksavvy.com     - 27.2ms                                             - LEN:1                                                 
7 - *                                                  - *                                                  - *                                                 
8 - *                                                  - *                                                  - *                                                 
9 - *                                                  - *                                                  - *                                                 
10 - *                                                  - *                                                  - *                                                 
11 - *                                                  - *                                                  - *                                                 
12 - *                                                  - *                                                  - *                                                 
13 - *                                                  - *                                                  - *                                                 
14 - *                                                  - *                                                  - *                                                 
15 - *                                                  - *                                                  - *
```

Thanks,

Comment: Some devices have bugs in the way they process TTL, which causes the duplicate lines 2 and 3.

Comment: Try performing a packet capture with tcpdump or Wireshark while you run your script and the standard traceroute, see if there's a difference in what you're sending and receiving.